# How to display an element when the checkbox with certain value is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three checkboxes and I want to show "text" below the form when "value C" is checked.
When only the checkbox "Value C" is checked, it seems to work.
But when I check multiple checkbox, for instance "Value A" and "Value C",
"text" doesn't appear.

I'd like to show "text" whenever "Value C" is checked.

Note: I can't change HTML code, as it is created by WordPress plugin.

```js
$(function() {
  var $input = $('input[name="name123[data][]"]');
  $input.change(function() {
    if ($('input[name="name123[data][]"]:checked').val() === 'value-c') {
      $('.text').show();
    } else {
      $('.text').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="name123[data][]" value="value-a"><span class="mwform-checkbox-field-text">Value A</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="name123[data][]" value="value-b"><span class="mwform-checkbox-field-text">Value B</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="name123[data][]" value="value-c"><span class="mwform-checkbox-field-text">Value C</span></label>
</form>
<div class="text">
  display this text in case "Value C" is checked
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select input using value attribute, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="name123[data][]"][value="value-c"]').change(function(e){
    $('.text').toggle($(e.target).is(':checked'))
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="name123[data][]" value="value-a"><span class="mwform-checkbox-field-text">Value A</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="name123[data][]" value="value-b"><span class="mwform-checkbox-field-text">Value B</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="name123[data][]" value="value-c" class="input--c"><span class="mwform-checkbox-field-text">Value C</span></label>
</form>
<div class="text">
  display this text in case "Value C" is checked
</div>
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know about "toggle" method, it's very useful.
Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could stick the value on the selector to explicitly check that input.  It's an ugly selector and could probably be done more efficiently, but it should work.

```
$('input[name="name123[data][]"]:checked[value="value-c"]').length
```

EDIT:
Actually looking at your logic, you already have the inputs cached in a variable, so you could also do...

```
$input.filter('[value="value-c"]:checked').length
```

This would remove the extra DOM lookup.

Comment: I would put the attribute selectors together and move the `:checked` pseudo class to the end (selectors are evaluated right to left). You could probably leave off `input` and `name`, unless you have other element with the same exact value attribute.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was looking at your comment and realized they already have a `$input` variable that could just be filtered on as well.